# CSS3 animation div position cause unclickable area and not trigger the animation

Tags: html, css, animation, position

I have tried to do an hover animation which brings the info from bottom to center, the problem is that the div position point starts too much from the bootom and it cause that the top and center area don't trigger the hover animation, only the bottom area triggered it. how can i fix the position of the div and still keep the animation from bottom?

here is the fiddle link: [js fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/zJLJp/16/)

the main issue is in this div:

```
.movie_thumb_wrapper .text-content {
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: table;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transform: translate(0,-150px);
    -webkit-transform: translate(0,100px);
    -o-transform: translate(0,-50px);
    -moz-transform: translate(0,-50px);
}
user agent stylesheetdiv {
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the selector

```
.movie_thumb_wrapper .text-content:hover
```

to

```
.movie_thumb_wrapper:hover .text-content
```

So that the transition takes place when hovering over the parent element instead:

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/p2LLbccx/)

```
.movie_thumb_wrapper:hover .text-content {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translate(0, -150px);
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0px);
    -o-transform: translate(0, -50px);
    -moz-transform: translate(0, -50px);
}
```